# Building book website, what APIs to use for and what to store in Database?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, api, database-design

I'm creating a book website where people can add books to their shelves. I'm currently planning on using the Amazon API or maybe Google books API. I'm unsure how to model it in the database though.

Should I look up a book once then store all the book's info in my database (ISBN, Description, Title, Author, etc) or should I look all this information up each time? Performance issues may lean toward lookup once, while having updated data leans toward lookup each time...

If I do store it in database, how do I keep database updated with Amazon (description or price, etc)?

If I look it up each time, how do I allow users to search for other uses using the same book? Maybe just store the ISBN?

Answer (score 1):

You can model the database with these tables to start with:

- Books
- Authors
- User/Customer
- BooksUserReading

When the user search for a book add them to your database. To keep the database updated with Amazon you can use a web service to run every 24 hours to check for updates.

Not sure how much this helps you.

Comment: So would you search the local database prior to accessing the API? The main use of the site is being able to see who else is reading similar so how would you deal with multiple versions of the same book to combine them all into a single item

Comment: Yes I would search the local database first. For multiple version of the same book that api should help you find if a book new/old edition. You might could make an edition/version lookup table to track this.